# cout << (1000 < pow(10,3)) << endl; gives 1

Tags: c++

I was just wondering why

```
cout << (1000 < 1000) << endl;
```

gives `0`, while

```
cout << (1000 < pow(10, 3)) << endl;
```

gives `1`.

Comment: All that the second statement would give you is a compiler error.

Comment: I've added the missing parenthesis.

Comment: That's floating point numbers for you - fiddly things

Comment: This is probably a result of floating point inaccuracy.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Comment: `pow(10,3)` is not exactly 1000 due to how it is computed: `exp(3*log(10))`, which gives something like `1000.0000000000007` in double precision.

Comment: @HristoIliev Wow I can't not believe you just did that

Comment: Another protential dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20756701/cmath-stdpow-function-giving-wrong-value-when-assigned-to-a-variable?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

[`std::pow`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/pow) does not work on integral types. If you supply it integers, it will cast them to `double` (see 7th overload on the linked page).
The result of the call is then a `double`, which happens to be slightly biased up (as floating-point arithmetic is lossy), enough to compare strictly larger with a literal value of `1000` directly converted to `double`.
See  [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Comment: Doubles (and floats for that matter) can exactly represent the numbers 10, 3 and 1000, so that isn't the issue. I suspect there is a difference in the implementation of `pow` between libraries.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy Indeed the issue is not representing the result, but calculating it. A converted literal does not have that problem, hence the difference.